# get file contents on file open event in windows using c#

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to get contents of file before it opens. I explored it on Internet but it didn't helped me more. Here is the code:

```
  FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
  NotifyFilters.FileName |
      NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.CreationTime;
  watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
  watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
  watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
  watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);                       
  watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
  watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

But it is not giving me a way to get file open event. Please help me to get the solution.

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a windows service, to run in the background and intercept any file open event that occurs in the operating system. If so, within this window service you should use a FileSystemWatcher object to intercept the opening of a file.

Comment: You want to read the content of the file twice I take?

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly if I assume that you want a notification when some other process **opens** some file for reading? That is not possible without creating some pretty low-level operating system hooks, which is really complicated! The `FileSystemWatcher` watches for **changes**, not for **reads**.

Comment: #Veverke Yes exactly and please see the code attached with the query I have used filesystemwatcher object but it doesn't provide me file open event like onChange or create event

Comment: #atornblad I am getting your answer but which type of hooks I didn't find those hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get contents *before* it opens, it sounds like you need a hook for the filesystem. In this case you need to learn windows kernel programming (and that will require you to use C++ or some other unmananaged language)

I can't think of an application that needs this other than antivirus/backup software.

I guess that releasing an application that hooks to the kernel requires code signing by Microsoft or a trusted entity.